# Find object in array of nested objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, find

```
const inventory = [
  { name: { vegetable: 'carrot' }, quantity: 2 },
  { name: { meat: 'pork' }, quantity: 0 },
  { name: { fruit: 'cherries' }, quantity: 5 },
];

const result = inventory.find(name => name === { fruit: 'cherries' });
console.log(result);
```

I have an array of nested objects and I'm trying to find out if there is one including the `{ fruit: 'cherries' }` object but I get undefined as a result.

So I guess you can't pass an object as a search parameter?

Comment: You can't compare objects like that, only compare references or primitive values.

Comment: As Hao Wu commented two objects can't be compared with strict equality `{ fruit : 'cherries' } === { fruit : 'cherries'}` will return `false`. So you get undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write full path to the object and access to object through `.` sign:

```
const result = inventory.find(name => name.name.fruit === 'cherries');
```

An example:

```js
const inventory = [
    { name: { vegetable: 'carrot' }, quantity: 2 },
    { name: { meat: 'pork' }, quantity: 0 },
    { name: { fruit: 'cherries' }, quantity: 5 },
  ];
  
  const result = inventory.find(name => name.name.fruit === 'cherries');
  console.log(result);
```

It will be better seen in debugger what there is actual path to your properties of object:

```
const result = inventory.find(name => {
    if(name.name.fruit === 'cherries')
        return name;
    return;
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please explore [Sbtree](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sbtree) module or [TyrDb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tyrdb) module (TyrDb is a wrapper on top of Sbtree with abstracted API). These libraries let you search nested element.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare objects because they have different *references*. One way could be using *destructuring* and just simply access the `fruit` *property* in order to compare it with a given *value*.

```js
const inventory = [
  { name: { vegetable: 'carrot' }, quantity: 2 },
  { name: { meat: 'pork' }, quantity: 0 },
  { name: { fruit: 'cherries' }, quantity: 5 },
];

const result = inventory.find(({name}) => name.fruit == "cherries");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the suggestions.
I think I found a solution to my problem.

I used `array.map` to create a new array consisting of only the **name objects**.
Then I used `JSON.stringify` on `selectedOption` and on the elements in the new array to find a match and/or index.

There is probably a better way of doing it but this is working OK.
Feel free to point out any potential flaws in my approach.

```js
const selectedOption = {fruit_red: "cherries", fruit_green: "kiwi"}
    
    const inventory = [
      { name: { vegetable: 'carrot' }, quantity: 2 },
      { name: { meat: 'pork' }, quantity: 0 },
      { name: { fruit_red: 'cherries', fruit_green: 'kiwi' }, quantity: 5 },
      { name: { fruit_red: 'cherries', fruit_green: 'apple' }, quantity: 3 },
    ];
    
    const names = inventory.map(item => item.name)
    
    const resultIndex = names.findIndex(name => JSON.stringify(name) === JSON.stringify(selectedOption));
    console.log(resultIndex)
    
    const result = names.find(name => JSON.stringify(name) === JSON.stringify(selectedOption));
    console.log(result)
    console.log(inventory[resultIndex])
```